# How to select the option which is in `location_id` in `shops` table in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-blade

```php
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Location</label>
        <select value="{{ $shop->location_id }}" name="location" class="form-control">
            @foreach ($locations as $location)
                <option value="{{$location->id}}">{{$location->address}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

> I have two table. `shops` and `locations`. `shops` table have a foreign key named `location_id` which is the foreign key of `locations` table. Now I can update the shops location in shops table. And `locations` table have some rows.

> The problem is when I update the `shop->location_id`. It updates. But when I update the shop again. Always `selected` the first one of `locations` table. But it should be selected the one which is actually the `$shops->location_id` How can I select the `location` which is in `shops` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use condition in you foreach. `{{ $shop->location_id == $location->id ? 'selected':'' }}`

full code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Location</label>
        <select value="{{ $shop->location_id }}" name="location" class="form-control">
            @foreach ($locations as $location)
                <option value="{{$location->id}}" {{ $shop->location_id == $location->id ? 'selected':'' }}>{{$location->address}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting value attribute to your `select` tag won't work. You need to compare your shop location id within the loop to add the `selected` attribute to the `option` tag

```
<select name="location" class="form-control">
            @foreach ($locations as $location)
                @if ($location->id == $shop->location_id)
                    <option value="{{$location->id}}" selected>{{$location->address}}</option>
                @else
                   <option value="{{$location->id}}">{{$location->address}}</option>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </select>
```